# Arcgis v10.2.4 ios and android sdk shows wrong cache data

Tags: android, scale, arcgis-android, arcgis-ios

I hava tiledmap and it's scale is 500.000 and when i tried to show on android or ios devices. It on mapview it brings me cached data of scale 300.000 but when i tried to show it on web page , it works correctly. Also i tried to show arcgis sample map , there is a same problem. Did you know something about it ?

Comment: you might be having a DPI issue whereby the display scale in the browser is genuinely different to the display scale on the mobile device. Are you using this function? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/api/com/esri/core/tasks/ags/identify/IdentifyParameters.html#setDPI(int)

Comment: This functions is for identity params but my problem is about view of map for example , when i open my map on android device  it is correct scale but cache image is not correct. If i open my map on web browser everything works correctly.